# Can an HTTP response include both a Location header and HTML content to render?

Tags: html, http, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, android-deep-link

I have a `GET` route which returns a `location` header with an app's scheme url, and Temporary Redirect status. In the case that a user accesses this on their phone and doesn't have the app installed, the browser will just render a blank page (makes sense).

If I were to include a regular HTML page in this response (e.g. a prettified `sorry you don't have our app`), does this break any standards? As far as I can see, a browser would just render this and not follow the redirect.